# Error CS0246 the type or namespace name 'XXXX' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net, namespaces, .net-assembly, cs0246

"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'BLLV2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) DMS_WEB D:\Projects\DMS_Web\DMS_WEB\AddCompBranch.aspx.cs   11  Active"

I have a Solution in which I hava 2 projects. 1 is 'BLLV2' and the second one is DMS_WEB. I have passed reference of BLLV2 in DMS_WEB when I compile I got Error List
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glwNr.png)
but when I Click to one Error it open that page and automatically is show "No Error Found" for specific page.
same I open all pages and till list goes to 0 when I build again it show error again for all pages.

Comment: Hi, could be your build order. set the Build order for your Solution, right-click on the Solution in Solution Explorer and Select Project Build Order:

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to add those DLLs which you have added in BLLV2 project for some other task. These are basically dependent DLLs.
Along with that you can also clean the solution and try to Rebuild project again.